# Расширение объектов по размеру окна Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет, у меня есть скрипт:

```
import tkinter as tk
from package import config as set

def check_answer():
   u_ans = answer_entry.get()

if u_ans == set.answers[set.current_question]:
    set.score += set.score_for_answer
    set.score += 10
    result_laber.config(text="Правильный ответ!", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
    set.question_generation()
    question_label.config(text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", fg='white')
else:
    result_laber.config(text="Неправильный ответ!", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
    set.score -= 10
    set.lifes -= 1
    lifes_label.config(text=set.lifes)
    if set.lifes < 1:
        window.destroy()
    else:
        set.question_generation()
        lifes_label.config(text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
        question_label.config(text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", fg='white')


def buy_lifes():
   if set.score >= 90:
    set.score -= 90
    set.lifes +=1
    bonus_output.config(text=f"Куплен бонус!", fg="green")
    lifes_label.config(text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}")
    
else:
    bonus_output.config(text="У вас недостаточно очков!", fg="red")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1000x500')

result_laber = tk.Label(window, text="Введите ответ, а тут появится статус", bg="#27261A", 
fg='white')
result_laber.pack()

question_label = tk.Label(window, text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", 
fg='white')
question_label.pack()

answer_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg="#27261A", fg='white')
answer_entry.pack()

submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Ответить", command=check_answer, bg="#27261A", 
fg='white')
submit_button.pack()

bonus_label = tk.Label(window, text="Покупка жизней", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
bonus_label.pack()

bonus_button = tk.Button(window, text="Купить", command=buy_lifes, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=2, 
bg="#27261A", fg="white")
bonus_button.pack()

# Настройка стиля кнопки
bonus_button.config(
   font=("Arial", 12),
   width=10,
   height=2
)

# Настройка закругления кнопки
bonus_button.config(
   borderwidth=0,
   highlightthickness=0,
   relief="solid"
)

bonus_output = tk.Label(window, text="", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
bonus_output.pack()

lifes_label = tk.Label(window, text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
lifes_label.pack()

window.configure(bg="#755A57")
window.mainloop()
```

Как привязать ширину объектов в размерам окна?

Comment: В простейшем случае в pack указываете нужные значения параметров fill и expand, примеры тут: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-pack/ В более сложных случаях (когда объекты не должны растягиваться на всю доступную ширину) возможно придется использовать grid вместо pack. В целом - все зависит от того, что конкретно вам нужно.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, статья помогла